# Apache Tomcat: .war files

Tags: tomcat, war

I'm developing a webapp using Apache Tomcat. I'm working offline. I was wondering if deploying a .war file with Tomcat manager was equivalent to copy all the files of my application in the "webapps" directory of Tomcat. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Note that deploying using the Manager webapp may give you a cleaner deployment, because Tomcat will not auto-redeploy the webapp while the Manager is installing the files (in case that takes a few seconds). If you just copy files, you run the risk of triggering an automatic reload while your files are still copying.

Answer (score 0):

Reading at Tomcat deployment documentation, it is the same.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup